# How do I merge two snippets in kaleidoscope?

Tags: text-editors, text-editing, kaleidoscope

I have two text snippets that I want to use to build (merge into each other) a third snippet.

How do I use Kaleidoscope to do this? I know Kaleidoscope can merge two things together, because I use it to do my git merge resolutions.

[image]

So, in this example, I want to use kaleidoscope to build a third snippet from these two snippets that says:

```
b.
c.
d.
f.
g.
h.
```

Note the addition of the "."s and "h" and the removal of the vowels "a" and "e". Basically, I want to use the diff between the two snippets as a starting point to help build an arbitrary third snippet (just like I'd be able to during a merge).

The "unified" view is not a valid answer because it does not allow manual edits the way the merged view does when using kaleidoscope to resolve a merge conflict:
[image: This is not the answer]

It needs to look like this (the middle pane is editable here):
[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Create 2 files (each with the contents of one of the snippets you want to merge)
2. Open terminal
3. Issue command:

   ksdiff --merge --output "snippet-new.txt" "snippet1.txt" "snippet2.txt"
4. Edit in center pane to your heart's content
5. Save and exit

[image]

Comment: If the two snippets came from a common source with different edits (as in a vas-style 3-way merge against a common ancestor), you can indicate the common ancestor with the `--base` command-line argument:
    `wsdiff --merge --output snippet-new.txt --base snippet-original.txt snippet1.txt snippet2.txt`